# Is it possible to connect to the internet over https from Google Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to use the pipeline to send documents in Google Storage to a web service that extracts data from them, before proceeding with ETL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is completely possible to connect to other web services over HTTPS from Google Cloud Dataflow. You can make as many HTTPS requests to your web service in a Dataflow transform.

On a different note, I would recommend having the data extraction logic to be written as a Dataflow transform for quicker results. While doing the HTTPS requests and sending files over from Google Cloud Storage to the web endpoint (assumed to be not present in GCP) egress cost should be taken into consideration.